# Why ruby Pathname#basename returns filename prefixed with "Pathname:"?

Tags: ruby

I want to get all files in directory besides hidden files (the files whose names starts with a dot):

```
@files = Pathname.new('.').children.select do |file|
  file.basename[0] != '.'
end
```

And I can't do that, cos #basename returns string in a form `"<#Pathname:.envrc>"`. So I need to make it `file.basename =~ '#<Pathname:.'`, Which for me seems weird.

Why do they prefix it with "Pathname" word?

Comment: Just use `to_s` method - http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/pathname/rdoc/Pathname.html#method-i-to_s

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the OP's answer, I think, it can be written as

```
@files = Pathname.new('.').children(false).reject do |file|
  file.to_s.start_with? '.'
end
```

Doc of [`children`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/pathname/rdoc/Pathname.html#method-i-children) is saying - *If you set with_directory to false, then the returned pathnames will contain the filename only.* It means, we will get all the basenames as *Pathname* object like `Pathname:.git`, `Pathname:English.rb`. Now applying `#to_s`, we will have then `'.git'`, `'English.rb'`. Thus, now we can use `String#start_with?` method on it to test if *it starts with `.` or not*.

Comment: I think, it's matter of personal taste to use to_s[0] == '.' or to_s.start_with? '.'. Also, thanks for children(false) tip.

Answer (score 2):

As Arup suggested, to list all files besides hidden files, I should do this:

```
@files = Pathname.new('.').children.select do |file|
  file.to_s[0] != '.'
end
```

Comment: But, why you want to test `.`.. As per the [doc](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/pathname/rdoc/Pathname.html#method-i-children) - *it nevers give `.` and `..` .. Why then you want to check ?*

Comment: I testing for hidden files, not for current directory